# How to synchronize a project in eclipse, which was imported with TortoiseSVN 1.8?

Tags: java, svn, tortoisesvn, repository, synchronize

I've imported a project from a repository using **TortoiseSVN 1.8**. When I open my project using **Eclipse Juno** I can't see the small SVN icons on the project, which means that there is no connection between the project and the repository.

I am using the default SVN version given with **Eclipse Juno**, and **JavaHL 1.7**.

How do I connect my project to the SVN repository?

Comment: Have you tried to update Eclipse to Kepler version? This version has Subclipse 1.10.x, which has SVN 1.8 support.

Answer (score 0):

Had the similar issue. This fixed for me.

Right click on the project and then

`Team -> Share Project -> SVN -> Create a new repository location`

Enter the folder path of the folder exluding Project folder name.

It will prompt that it will override the changes as it finds an existing project at that location. But in your case, both will be same. So ignore and continue.

Done!